# Is there any way to redraw only one View?

Tags: android

I have GroupView which contains 4 ImageViews.

When I change params of one view(for example re scale image or rotate) this causes to redraw whole Layout.

I want to prevent redrawing whole layout and want to redraw only specific View.

Comment: did you find a solution? I have exactly the same problem

Answer (score 2):

Sure.

```
myView.invalidate()
```

See:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate()

> Drawing is handled by walking the tree and recording the drawing
>   commands of any View that needs to update. After this, the drawing
>   commands of the entire tree are issued to screen, clipped to the newly
>   damaged area.
>
> The tree is largely recorded and drawn in order, with parents drawn
>   before (i.e., behind) their children, with siblings drawn in the order
>   they appear in the tree. If you set a background drawable for a View,
>   then the View will draw it before calling back to its onDraw() method.
>   The child drawing order can be overridden with custom child drawing
>   order in a ViewGroup, and with setZ(float) custom Z values} set on
>   Views.
>
> To force a view to draw, call invalidate().